# Split costs and one pay $X%$ more?

Tags: economics, percentages

```
If combined costs are 23000 and you where to split it in two 
and then one should pay 18% more, how do you count that?

23 000 / 2 = 11 500
11 500 * 0.82 = 9 430
11 500 - 9 430 = 2 070
11 500 + 2 070 = 13 570

so its 13 570 for one to pay and 9 430 for the other? , isnt that 30% more?

( (13 570-9 430) / 13 570) = 0.31 = 31% ?

-----------------------------------------------

Is this calc wrong?

218 = 100 + 100 + X% (X = 18)

23 000 / 218 = 105.5

105.5 * 100 = 10 550
105.5 * 118 = 12 449.5

so one pay 10 550 and the other 12 449.5?
```

Comment: The wording in the question is a bit unclear, but I took a stab at it. Let me know if I understood the question. Also, where are the 0.83 and 0.17 coming from? Is the problem asking for 18% or 17%?

Comment: yes, typo, fixed the example to have 18% instead, :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the question. See below...

> We have $23,000. It must be split among two individual such that one person pays 18% more than the other person. What does each person pay?

Let $x$ represent the *smaller* amount that one individual pays. Then the other individual, who pays $18\%$ *more* must pay $x+0.18x = 1.18x$.

Together, they must have $23,000, so

$$x + 1.18x = 23000$$
$$2.18x = 23000$$
$$x \approx \$10550.46$$

That's the amount one pays. The other pays

$$1.18x \approx \$12449.54$$

Comment: Yes, an amount of money split in two and one should pay 18% more, so my second calculation (despite some typos) was most correct it seems.